# Changing size of UI Instance shown over sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am showing a Modal Dialog on the screen and I can set its size in units of pixels, however, people use different resolutions, so it might cut off on some computers. What I want to do is have the UI be full screen, in essence 100% x 100%. I am wondering if there is a way to do that.

```
function test() {
  //I can set size in units of pixels here
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(700).setWidth(1500);
  var label = app.createLabel("Hi").setId("label");
  app.add(label);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(app, 'Test');
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UiApp has no way to know the size of the browser view port, this can't be done.

Comment: hmm, besides hosting as a web app, is there any other solutions for the effect I'm trying to go for?